# I am creating a new contribution page but am stuck because it keeps saying a supporter profile is mandatory

Tags: contributions, contribution-page, recurring-contributions, donations, simple-donate-form

I am on http://civicrm.test/civicrm/admin/contribute/pcp
trying to create a supporter profile solely because the form doesn't seem to want to save unless I do so.  I have put "supporter profile" & saved but that doesn't work.  I have tried to press create but it asks me for options that don't make sense.
Has anyone else had a problem creating contribution pages for this reason?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you click the help icon - it has some info and maybe some of it is relevant - `The profile you select must be configured with 'Account creation required' (under Profile Settings » Advanced Settings). You must include an Email address field`

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't but I figured it out.  Thank you.  I guess the default is that it uses the admin's email